How to alter script to list VMAgent_Status as Not Ready
I have some virtual machines that are Running, but the Agent Status is showing Not Ready. I have a Powershell script that lists all the VMs in my Azure Subscription with VM_Name, ResourceGroup_Name, VMAgent_Status and VM_Agent_Version.
This is the script:
Set-AzContext -Subscription "My-AZ-Sub"
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$output = @()
$VMs_running = Get-AzVM  -status | ?{$_.PowerState -eq 'VM running'}

 
foreach($VM in $VMs_running)
{
    $VM_status = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Status

    $Row = "" | select Name, ResourceGroupName, VMAgent_Status, VMAgent_Version
    $Row.Name = $VM_status.Name
    $Row.ResourceGroupName = $VM_status.ResourceGroupName
    $Row.VMAgent_Status = $VM_status.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus
    $Row.VMAgent_Version = $VM_status.VMAgent.VmAgentVersion
    
 
    $output += $Row
}
 
$output

This is an example of the output:
Name              : My-VM
ResourceGroupName : My-RG
VMAgent_Status    : Ready
VMAgent_Version   : 2.7.41491.1239

Is there a way I can add to the script to only list VMs that have VMAgent_Status to equal Not ready?

if($VM_status -ne "Ready"){ .....}

Hello, so I tried the following:
`foreach($VM in $VMs_running)
{
$VM_status = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Status
if($VM_status -ne "Ready")
{
$Row = "" | select Name, ResourceGroupName, VMAgent_Status, VMAgent_Version
$Row.Name = $VM_status.Name
$Row.ResourceGroupName = $VM_status.ResourceGroupName
$Row.VMAgent_Status = $VM_status.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus
$Row.VMAgent_Version = $VM_status.VMAgent.VmAgentVersion
$output += $Row
}

}
$output`

Did the code work?

No, it output the vms that have an agent status of Ready.

You are not getting an error, just not getting what you are expecting!!!  So Get-AzVM is returning a different object than what you are expecting.  The issue is with Get-AzVM, not your code.


Is there a way I can add to the script to only list VMs that have VMAgent_Status to equal Not ready?

To list out the Virtual machines that has VMAgent_Status is not ready, use below script.
$output = @()
$VMs_running = Get-AzVM  -status | ?{$_.PowerState -eq 'VM running'}
foreach($VM in $VMs_running)
{
    $VM_status = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Status

    $Row = "" | select Name, ResourceGroupName, VMAgent_Status, VMAgent_Version
    $Row.Name = $VM_status.Name
    $Row.ResourceGroupName = $VM_status.ResourceGroupName
    $Row.VMAgent_Status = $VM_status.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus
    $Row.VMAgent_Version = $VM_status.VMAgent.VmAgentVersion
    if ($Row.VMAgent_Status -ne "Ready"){
      $output += $Row
    }
}
 $output

Output:
In my environment, all the virtual machine agents are in a ready status, as shown in the below output. Hence, I have received empty results.

Below is the output if I have given Agent status is in ready state.


Thank you so much for your help on this!
So if I wanted to add a condition where if the output is empty, then print "All VMs are Ready"
I tried this, however I added it as an else clause underneath the if statement:
Else     {     Write-Host "All VMs are Ready"     }
This works, however, it prints it the number of times VMs in my subscription exist (continuously).
